# upgrade iBatis 2 MyBatis 3: nullValue and defaultValue

Tags: sql, mybatis

What is the "official" way to migrate:
- nullValue : substitute database null with real number (i.e. -1)
- INTEGER:-1 : a default value when writing from object to database

nullValue behaviour can be obtained by altering the sql of the 
default values can be imposed by dynamic sql () as in
-1#{hitCount}

However, this could turn out to be a bit verbose, and involve much work when
migrating existing projects. 
A good alternative could be to write a typeHandler, but this precludes handling on a field basis (it would show the behaviour for all fields of type INTEGER).

Is there a better way? (more elegant, more efficient)

Comment: Maybe you can show a sample of what you have in mind? So that others might be able to address accordingly?